# How to change Snap-Ins onClick for offline button?

Tags: javascript, html, liveagent, einstein

Here is what I have so far. I have here commented out towards the bottom, some attempts at trying to accomplish what I have in the question. I have tried changing the href for the offline button, I have tried adding another eventlistener, I have tried changing the onClick method. I am unsure what I am doing wrong or if this is even something possible.

I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks!

```
            <a href="#" onclick="initLiveChat()">Click Here for Chat </a>

            <style type='text/css'>
            /*this is css for short header*/
            .embeddedServiceSidebarHeader .shortHeader {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(13, 19, 23, 0.4);


            }
            /*this is the css for the minimized button*/
                .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton { background-color: #0097ed; font-family: "Salesforce Sans", sans-serif; }

                .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton:hover{ background-color: #00e3c8; }

                .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton:focus {
                    outline: 1px solid #005290;
                    text-decoration: none;
                 }
                 .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton:active {
                    text-decoration: none;
                 }

                 .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .helpButtonEnabled:hover::before, .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .helpButtonEnabled:focus::before{

                     background-color:#00e3c8;
                     text-decoration: none;
                 }

                /*this is the css for the chat submit button*/
                .embeddedServiceSidebarButton:not(:disabled):hover {
                    background: #00e3c8;
            }

            /*this is the css for chat widget when prechat form in initiated*/
            .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI.helpButton {
                    background-color: #0097ed;
                    border-color: #0097ed;
                }
            .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI.helpButton:not(:disabled):hover{
                        background-color: #00e3c8;
                        border-color: #00e3c8;


                    }
            .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI.minimizedContainer:focus{
                                text-decoration: none;
                                background-color: #0097ed;


                    }

                    /*this is the css for the widget once you have a new message*/
                    .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI.newMessage, .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI.idleTimeout{
                        background-color: #0097ed;
                        border-color: #0097ed;
                    }

                    /*general*/
                    .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI{
                        background-color: #0097ed;
                        border-color: #0097ed;
                    }
                    .embeddedServiceSidebarMinimizedDefaultUI:not(:disabled):hover{
                        background-color: #00e3c8;
                        border-color: #00e3c8;
                    }
                @font-face {
                font-family: 'Salesforce Sans';
                src: url('https://www.sfdcstatic.com/system/shared/common/assets/fonts/SalesforceSans/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
                url('https://www.sfdcstatic.com/system/shared/common/assets/fonts/SalesforceSans/SalesforceSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
                }
            </style>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            var initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
            embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
            embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'

            //prechat bg image
            embedded_svc.settings.prechatBackgroundImgURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/wh-site/logo.png"


            //embedded_svc.settings.defaultMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Chat with an Expert)
            //embedded_svc.settings.disabledMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Agent Offline)

            //embedded_svc.settings.loadingText = ''; //(Defaults to Loading)

            //uncomment when ready to deploy
            //embedded_svc.settings.storageDomain = 'whitehawk.com'; //(Sets the domain for your deployment so that visitors can navigate subdomains during a chat session)

            // Settings for Live Agent
            //embedded_svc.settings.directToButtonRouting = function(prechatFormData) {
            // Dynamically changes the button ID based on what the visitor enters in the pre-chat form.
            // Returns a valid button ID.
            //};
            //embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields = {}; //Sets the auto-population of pre-chat form fields
            //embedded_svc.settings.fallbackRouting = []; //An array of button IDs, user IDs, or userId_buttonId
            //embedded_svc.settings.offlineSupportMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Contact Us)

            embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
            embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';

            embedded_svc.init('https://whitehawk.my.salesforce.com', 'https://whitehawk.force.com',
             gslbBaseURL,
             '00Dj0000001njgp',
             'Main_Site_Chat_Window',
              { baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la3-c1-phx.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                 deploymentId: '5720a000000LBvm',
                 buttonId: '5730a000000LDYR',
                 baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la3-c1-phx.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                  eswLiveAgentDevName: 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Parent04I0a000000XZJAEA4_16437c08c13',
                    isOfflineSupportEnabled: false}); };
                    if (!window.embedded_svc) {
                        var s = document.createElement('script');
                        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://whitehawk.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
                        s.onload = function() { initESW(null); };
                        document.body.appendChild(s);
                    } else {
                        initESW('https://service.force.com');
                }


                //document.getElementsByClassName("uiButton helpButtonDisabled").href('https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/WhiteHawkCECInc@whitehawk.com/bookings/');

            /*document.getElementsByClassName("uiButton helpButtonDisabled").addEventListener("click", function(){
            window.open('https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/WhiteHawkCECInc@whitehawk.com/bookings/');
            } );

            */
            function initLiveChat(){
            document.getElementsByClassName("helpButton")[0].childNodes[0].click();

            }

            </script>



            <script type = "text/javascript">
            function bookings() {
            console.log("The offline button has been clicked");

            window.open('https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/WhiteHawkCECInc@whitehawk.com/bookings/');
            } ;

            var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("uiButton no-hover helpButtonDisabled");
            for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
            classname[i].addEventListener("click",bookings,false);
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Snap-Ins Chat is built from a particular Chat Button. If you ahve a look at the Live Agent settings for the Snap-Ins Chat it should tell you which one. Have look at the code for that Chat Button. The code looks like

```
<a id="liveagent_button_online_5XXXXXXXXXXvlQ" 
href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" 
onclick="liveagent.startChat('5XXXXXXXXXXvlQ')"><!-- Online Chat 
Content --></a><div id="liveagent_button_offline_5XXXXXXXXXXvlQ" 
style="display: none;"><!-- Offline Chat Content --></div><script 
type="text/javascript">
.....
```

If you can get a reference to the liveagent_button_offline_5XXXXXXXXXXvlQ div maybe you can add an onClick handler to it.